# I'd like to find a particular book about Pearl Harbor

Tags: identification-request

I was browsing through a library, and a book caught my eye.  I pulled it out to look, and the opening paragraph was so stupid that I immediately put it back.  I went back a few weeks later because I wanted to show someone else this amazing thing.  :-)  But it wasn't there.

The book was about Pearl Harbor, but I don't remember whether those words were on the cover.  What was so memorable (and the reason I want to find it again) was the stupid intro, something like

> It was a day like any other. Fathers getting ready for work; children
>   getting ready for school.

I tried parts of those sentences in the Google Books exact phrase, but no hits.  I must be remembering some of the words wrong.

Catija found something similar (and **equal** in the author's apparent ignorance of which weekday), but I don't think it was the same book.

Interestingly, Google has apparently not scanned the book Catija found.  Searching "people at Pearl Harbor were going about their morning" gets a *not found, perhaps you want (this SE post).*

Comment: What section of the library were you in?

Comment: History section, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: So it was non-fiction?

Comment: :-) Well, it was apparently intended to be non-fiction, but with an intro like that ...

Comment: This phrase sounds so familiar to me (and Catija's answer doesn't) that I wonder if it's a common platitude in accounts of Pearl Harbour.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Same... :) I initially posted it as a comment before I found the first page because it was so obscure but...

Comment: Wait... was that *actually* the right book?

Comment: What's stupid?  Getting ready for work and school on a Sunday in 1941?   I _hope_ that's not a common platitude.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I'm not the sort of person who could tell you off the top of my head what day of the week today is, let alone Dec. 7, 1941, so I gathered from the quotation that it must have been a weekday. It's been years since I listened to FDR's Pearl Harbor speech, which does mention it being a Sunday; and on the actual day of the attack I was probably oblivious to the whole thing, being 5 years old. Of course, even on a Sunday in 1941, quite a few people would be going to work. Maybe not so many children going to school.

Comment: Well, I was "minus thirteen" then, but I heard it so often mentioned that it was Sunday … Remembering the poor quality of my own history classes, I guess I can understand why some wouldn't know that.  But there's still no excuse for the author writing it and the publisher not catching it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer because it seems incredibly similar to what you're talking about... enough so that I feel it's worth posting.

The book *Voices from the Camps: Internment of Japanese Americans During World War II* by Larry Dane Brimner starts with a chapter about Pearl Harbor with the chapter title "A date which will live in infamy". The first paragraph doesn't contain the text you remember, but the third one does, pretty closely:

> As the Japanese planes advanced, people at Pearl Harbor were going about their morning routines. Children were getting ready for school. Adults were preparing for the workday ahead.

I found a scan of the book on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/voicesfromcampsi00brim), which is the source of this image:

[image: First page of "Voices from the Camps"]

It is a short book, only 110 pages and is classified as "juvenile literature".

Comment: I'm accepting this, even though the image is not from the book I saw.  Perhaps a different edition.  The one I encountered had wider text column.  Also, it was not in the juvenile section, but looking at the wording, I wouldn't have classified it as juvenile.

Comment: "Juvenile" includes high school... which is the reading level of many non-juvenile books anyway... so that doesn't *necessarily* mean much. I think this was classified somewhere I saw as ninth grade.

Comment: OK, in the library where I found it, "juvenile" is grade school, and teenagers are (improperly, IMHO) "young adult."  But the book I asked about was in neither of those sections.

Comment: So... It's not that I don't appreciate the reputation... if you really think this might be the wrong book, you're better served leaving it unaccepted as others may know of a different book that has a similar text.

Comment: Re-accepted as no other answer offered, and Google still can’t find the quote I remember.  Perhaps my memory is faulty.  The viewing happened between 1996 and 2011, and when I returned to the library to check out the book, I couldn’t find it.